# Is it possible that an image of a given size of 26 * 7 can contain 78 separate colour values in each row of the Mat ,and another can contain 77?

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

Is it possible that an image of a given size of 26 * 7 can contain 78,77 or 79 values in each row of the Mat?Why is this so? I have 95 images all of which are 26 by 7,I discovered that some images have 77 separate color values on each row,others have 79.This is problematic,since I need a standard value.

This is how the images are cropped to a size of 26 by 7.

```
Mat standard_size=largestObject1(Rect(0,0,26,7));//a template to get the standard _size of a binary image
cv::resize(thresholdi,thresholdi,standard_size.size());
```

If I could convert it to only 26 pixel values,would I lose information?

```
I create the following code:-

    ofstream in("Eye_Gestures.txt");
    //Eye Graze Class
     IplImage *img2 = cvLoadImage("eye2.bmp");
     Mat imgg2=cvarrToMat(img2);
     Formatted line0i2 = format(imgg2.row(0),"CSV" ); 
     Formatted line1i2 = format(imgg2.row(1),"CSV" ); 
     Formatted line2i2 = format(imgg2.row(2),"CSV" );
     Formatted line3i2 = format(imgg2.row(3),"CSV" ); 
     Formatted line4i2 = format(imgg2.row(4),"CSV" );
     Formatted line5i2 = format(imgg2.row(5),"CSV" ); 
     Formatted line6i2 = format(imgg2.row(6),"CSV" );

     in<<line0i2<<", "<<line1i2<<", "<<line2i2<<", "<<line3i2<<", "<<line4i2<<", "<<line5i2<<", "<<line6i2<<", "<<EyeGraze<<endl;
```

I need to ensure that each row stores the same number of separate colour values for all 95 images.If it going to be 77  values ,it needs to be 77 for all rows for each image.How can I ensure that I pass 77 not 78 or 79 values to the text file?How can I disregard the excess values for each row?how can I keep track of separate colour values on a row without having to manually count them?

Comment: How did you find these deviations? By manually counting CSV entries? Most likely you just miscounted somewhere.

Comment: And I assume the number of values you are talking about are the separate color values, which would then be 26*3 = 78 for images without alpha channel.

Comment: Yes I am referring to the separate colour values.You are correct about the 26*3 giving me 78 for the images.I think this might have to deal with the format Im storing the images. Im storing them as a bmp. Which format will store just 26 separate colour values to the textfile. Im using these values has training samples for a neural network.

Comment: A bmp stores 3 values for each pixel. I don't know of any format that uses only 1 value per pixel (but perhaps there is some ancient grayscale-only format?). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I created 95 bmp images for my training sample that I will be using to train my ANN(neural network).Im storing each row of the Mat on a single line in the textfile ,the next attribute will be my classlabel.For each line in the text file ,Im exacting individual attributes and storing it in a single floating point vector using data.at<float>(linet, attribute) = tmpf .The last attribute will be stored into another vector containing the class values.It is very important that I know number of values and that it is consistent.

Comment: And  yes you might suggest that I could increase my vector size to 95 by 78*7=546 values from 95 by 182. However,for some images my color values on each row differs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [bitmap (bmp)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Bitmap)  image contains exactly 1 entry for each pixel. Depending on the type of bitmap you are using, these may be of different (but always constant) resolution.

The method you are using for converting the bmp to csv text representation seems to serialize each pixel as a set of 3 values (possibly rgb). If in an image with a width of 26px you are getting a different number of entries per line than 78, you most likely made some mistake when reading the file.

Common mistakes would be 0 values expressed as empty cells ",," or - depending on the locale you are using - confusion between the decimal comma character and the csv separator.

Are you sure the separator is indeed the `','` character you are using for separating the lines when writing to the output stream which is confusingly named `in`?

Comment: Before the image is saved ,it contains and displays exactly 1 entry for each pixel for both default format and CSV format.When loading the saved image ,even when displaying the default format not CSV,each pixel is represented as a set of 3 values RGB. The RGB values are equal.I then stored an image in png format, the same scenario occurs.How can I obtain just 1 entry for each pixel,after it is saved.

Comment: Mat imgg=cv::imread("eye.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);           CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED (<0) loads the image as is (including the alpha channel if present).Refer to http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html .Thank you Hulk for the help,really appreciate it.Learnt alot.

Answer (score 1):

An image of 26 by 7 pixels contains 7 rows of 26 pixels each. There won't be 27, let alone 77 pixels on one row. You're entirely confused.

Go back an rethink what you're actually trying to achieve. Note that text files are not a natural format for image files.